# Is there a closed form of standard deviation of the min. entropy of a set?

Tags: information-theory, descriptive-statistics

Min. entropy $(H_{\infty})$of a set is defined as $ -\log_2(p_{max}) $ where $p_{max}$ is the highest probability of occurrence of any individual element of the set. There is also the $\chi^2$ distribution of those elements. I know how to calculate that too.

In my water I feel that these two metrics are closely related. Is it possible that there is a formula for calculating the standard deviation of the min.entropy? This seems comparable to calculating the [standard deviation of the mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation#Standard_deviation_of_the_mean) of a set. If it helps, I'm specifically interested in discrete sets of bytes, i.e. sets that are uniformly and randomly distributed as $\mathcal{U}(0, 255)$.

Having simulated this calculation for a sample set of 512,000 random bytes, and 100,000 independent trials, I get:-

[image: chart]

Notice that this is not a Normal distribution. So from the above, $ E(H_{\infty}(X)) \approx 7.912 $ bits/byte.

Answer (score 3):

Consider the uniform distribution on $\{0,1,\ldots,n-1\}$ and let $X$ have that distribution. The variance of this distribution is $(n^2-1)/12$ and its standard deviation is $\sqrt{(n^2-1)/12}.$ However, what we want is the standard deviation of the min-entropy of $X,$ not that of $X$ itself.

What happens when we sample? We obtain an empirical distribution, which is like a balls-in-bins process with each ball landing in each of $n$ bins independently and with equal likelihood.

If we throw $m$ balls then for $n$ large enough, and $m$ also growing with $m,$ there is a concentration phenomenon and the most loaded bin (i.e., the one with the highest empirical probability) has a load that is almost surely determined.

Note your $n$ is now $m,$ while the $n$ here is the number of outcomes, i.e., $n=256$ for your question.

See the paper by Raab and Steger available [here](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/3-540-49543-6_13) or without a paywall [here](https://www.ic.unicamp.br/%7Ecelio/peer2peer/math/balls-into-bins.pdf), specifically Theorem 1. If, for example, you have $m\leq c n \log n,$ then with high probability (and ignoring the fine dependence on $\alpha$ since it is multiplied by $\log \log  n$ divided by $\log n$) the most loaded bin has no more than
$$
\log n/(n \log n/m)
$$
balls.

If however $m$ is much larger than $n$ (last case of theorem) then the most loaded bin has no more than
$$
\frac{m}{n}+\sqrt{\frac{2m \log n}{n}}
$$
balls.

If you divide these quantities by $m$ (number of balls) to get the highest empirical probability for a bin load and take the reciprocal and the log this should give you an estimate of the sample min-entropy.

However, experiments are probably required to see how large $n$ and $m$ need to be for this analysis to hold.

Comment: I did some (see edit).  Does it make a difference please?

Comment: The link is dead